# How to access Tracker (antonioribeiro/tracker) object In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, object, tracking, tracker

I am using [AntonioRiveiro/Tracker](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) repo for my [laravel](https://laravel.com/) app. I would like to add some more functionality to it that it doesn't have out of the box.

1. But I can't find where its instance gets created, or how to access the `Tracker` object in my Controllers.
2. Or how do I extend the tracker object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think the easiest way for you to go about this is the following:

First, make your own ServiceProvider

```
php artisan make:provider CustomTrackerServiceProvider
```

Now open up that file, we'll need to make some modifications.

Firstly, we'll need to extend the ServiceProvider that Tracker provides.

```
use PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider as TrackerServiceProvider

class CustomTrackerServiceProvider extends TrackerServiceProvider
```

The `use` alias above is not required, but I prefer it for clarity given the similar naming convention to the core framework.

Now you'll need to replace your usage of the `PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider` in your `config/app.php` file under the `providers array`

```
config/app.php
'providers' => [
    //other providers and what have you
    App\Http\Providers\CustomTrackerServiceProvider::class
]
```

Now you have the ability to make changes. You can override the default functionality of the core class as long as it's member is not `private`.

Have a look at the vendor provided file and identify a similar architecture pattern to the vendor maintainer, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough walkthrough on how to extend the functionality!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question provides a solution for (2), I found the answer to (1) [here](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker/issues/173).

To access the tracker object you need to include:

```
use PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Facade as tracker;
```

Then you'll do something like:

```
$visitor = Tracker::currentSession();
```

as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker#usage).